# Laravel 5.3 web guard allows login but admin guard does not allow login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

/* Foundation-Auth */

AuthenticateUsers.php in laravel->foundation/auth

```
return $this->guard('admin')->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    );
```

Comment: Please check if you have extended `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticable` instead of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` in your Admin Model that you are using for Auth Guard Provider Class...

Comment: Yes I have already done that.. 
what i am looking for is to let admin to login.. the admin guard check the admin model but redirect back to the same login page and does not login to dashboard page.

Comment: You have to add your routes inside a group with middleware `auth:admin` to specify `Authenticate` middleware to use admin guard.

Comment: So can we login both user and admin from same login form ?@TipuZaynSultan
As I am using  laravel make:auth..

Comment: I don't think so... Because you have to use the guard to authenticate. So you are going to need a guard method in your LoginController for admin as well as User side. So you have to create one more LoginController inside Controllers/Auth/Admin Directory. To handle that. And you are going to need a separate form to hit the methods on that Controller.